# Impact of unique partition key on DynamoDB performance

Tags: amazon-web-services, dynamodb-queries, amazon-dynamodb

I have the following table structure. My `partitionKey` currently are not unique however my `sortKey` is unique.

I also have a `Global Secondary Index` where my column `Column Units` is the partitionKey which is unique.

> Will removing the `GSI` and making the `partitionKey` to `Column Units` which is unique make my queries faster and reduce latency.

Reason, I am asking is occasionally I see a spike in `DDB` calls to this table.

```
Current Table Structure
GSI - Column Units
```

| Column Zone (partitionKey) | Column Units (sortKey) |
| --- | --- |
| A | unique-1 |
| A | unique-2 |
| B | unique-3 |

Comment: How do you request data, i.e. what are the access patterns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing or Adding Global Secondary Index has no impact on the performance of the base table. A global secondary index is a **separate** table under the hood and data from the base table get's replicated to it asynchronously.

If you use the `GetItem` API to request items, it shouldn't matter if you have a primary key (only partition key) or composite primary key (partition key and sort key).

Answer (score 1):

In your case it is okay to duplicate the partition key as you are using a sort key too, if you only use the partition key with duplicate values ​​you will have issues in dynamoDB partitions the data.

DynamoDB stores and retrieves each item based on the primary key value, which must be unique. Items are distributed across 10-GB storage units.

For tables with composite primary keys, the sort key may be used as a partition boundary. DynamoDB splits partitions by sort key if the collection size grows bigger than 10 GB.